# Bolting on abstract behavior dependent upon the same base?

Tags: python, oop, game-engine, object-oriented-analysis

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me out with a design issue I'm dealing with. It's specifically in the game development domain, but I think it's really a broader issue that has probably been solved in an accepted way. I'm working in Python.

I have a GameObject class that holds the position of the object (and other general state attributes) and a reference to my Engine object, which holds information about the game world at large. GameObjects can be a categorized further: they can be VisibleGameObjects, PhysicalGameObjects (collidable), or both, in concrete form. For example, I could have an invisible boundary, which is physical, but does not have a visible representation.

VisibleGameObjects implement a draw() method that handles drawing functionality, delegating this through its parent's Engine reference. PhysicalGameObjects have bounding boxes, and define logic to handle collisions, also requiring access to GameObject attributes (acceleration, velocity, etc.)

The problem is, what happens when I'd like to define a concrete object that needs to inherit the behavior of both a VisibleGameObject, and a PhysicalGameObject (which both share a parent GameObject)? It's my understanding that this type of circular inheritance is a big-bad idea.

How can I refactor this to essentially bolt on the specific behaviors to a concrete child class (drawable, collidable) that depend on the state of the parent abstract class?

EDIT: My one thought was to assign them to concrete instances of GameObjects as components, favoring a has-a relationship over an is-a relationship. Even that doesn't seem so clean however; trying to check to see if an object is collidable by searching a "components" list for a collidable component doesn't seem great either.

Comment: At first read - it sounds like Physical and Visible should be attributes of the object, rather than separate classes

Comment: @JonClements I think the issue here is that he wants to expose different class functions. I think the proper term would be a *trait*

Comment: @goncalopp could well be - but think I'm burnt out now - been at the computer on/off for pretty much 20 hours sorting stuff out before the festive period - think I'll retire now!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for a [trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29)

Unfortunately, python doesn't support traits natively, although there are [multiple](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/traits) [modules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/strait) that try to implement the model.

My suggestion (unless you want to depend on the mentioned modules) would be to write abstract classes to expose the behaviour you want, but that don't inherit the main class - leaving that to a third class, which inherits both the main, and the behaviour-class.

It's probably less confusing with an example:
create a `Visible` abstract class that does **not** inherit from `GameObject`, and exposes all the intended behaviour/functions (**as if** it inherited from `GameObject`). Then, have `VisibleGameObject` inherit from both `GameObject` and `Visible`.

Obviously, you can only manage to write `Visible` on a dynamic language like python - otherwise the compiler would complain that it couldn't access inexistent fields.

Comment: Interesting, so how would something like this be implemented in C++? It's looking like perhaps my core design is off, and I should reconsider the behavior of my acting objects..

Comment: @Drism I've never done it myself in C++, but [templates seem sufficient for the job](http://accu.org/index.php/articles/442). This is a very recurrent pattern when you deal with this kind of problems. I don't think there's a way to avoid it entirely, but traits (native in languages like scala) are a very good solution, IMHO